# Scheduled download by transmission during nightly hours? (downloading just at a specified period of a day)

Tags: downloads, transmission, schedule

I want to limit transmission to work at 02:00 AM untill 08:00. How?

Comment: Feature request for scheduling downloads:
https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/948

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Speed Limit in Transmission throttles the upload/download speeds during the time set. What you want to do is set the upload/download speed values to 0 and implement that starting at 0800 and end at 0200. That should deactivate all uploads/downloads starting at 8am until 2am the following day.

[image: transmission preference]

Comment: You can always set a general throttling policy in Transmission to limit bandwidth usage. If you modify the Speed Limits for `Scheduled Times:` as I explained, that will enable uploads/downloads only between 2am and 8am as you wanted. The settings you had entered _disabled_ uploads/downloads during the time you actually wanted it to be active.

Comment: No, more like [this](http://flic.kr/p/eeyWAH).

Comment: I've just tried this, but it's not an ideal solution I think. Transmission still connects to peers so it's still active. Do you know of a way Transmission is completely inactive between certain periods of the day?

Answer (score 7):

I was going to use the above scheduled throttling, but thought of something additional and that is to just use the cron daemon via a start and stop: (e.g. Add the following to cron jobs via `crontab -e`)

```
 * 2 * * *  sudo service transmission-daemon start
 * 8 * * *  sudo service transmission-daemon stop
```

for you 2am-8am schedule. Perhaps even start it a little (5 minutes?) earlier/later?

The only problem I see from this though, is that the service won't be running *during the day*, when you want to add new torrents. 
So you'd have to start/stop manually whenever you are adding torrents (per "session")

Depending on your habits, this may/may not be convenient...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) The existing answer is a bit simpler to implement then yours, but yours would consume less memory..  *But* you need to enable the daemon (which is lacking in your answer) There also is a spelling error in your output and your answer does not contain the `crontab` command to make this work.

**Therefore:** please update your answer to make it a full-fledged working solution and drop me a note @Fabby so I can upvote it, or delete this answer altogether to get rid of the negative reputation points you now got...

Comment: Thanks. The spelling was a bad typo, sorry. I've assumed the OP already has the daemon enabled etc, but added what I thought you meant about crontab command...
My answer was really intended as a response to the comment from @duxk.gh  - but Stack exchange doesn't let those under 30rep comment (but I can answer?)

Comment: There.  made it a bit more "professional" and upvoted.  Always use the logic of the person asking 2AM-8AM, so also put the start/stop in that order...  Review my edits: http://askubuntu.com/posts/581994/revisions

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and there is no service with that name `transmission-daemon` ??

Comment: @Fabby the graphic UI didn't works from me , and it more confuse even I select slow download transmitter still download the files on day time ! Sadly this solution didn't work wither I got `Failed to start transmission-daemon.service: Unit transmission-daemon.service not found.`

Comment: @SalemF That would be a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  **;-)** Please provide a link to this question if it would provide context.

Comment: No need I just have to install it manually  `sudo apt-get install transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon`

Comment: The daemon starts only when running cron as root *sudo crontab -e* 

However, my already loaded torrents are not running when the daemon starts (they only run when I launch the gui version of transmission). Any idea how to solve this? @Fabby